# Handle binary data at backend using golang

Tags: go

I don't even know if i had asked the right question or not, but here it go anw.

The question is which data type in golang i should use to store binary data

In the front end i using vuejs and sending a file with axios post request using formData as request body.
1 field in this body is a file which if i check in the devtool it show as (binary) like this : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaor3.png)

and if i console log it's type then it show as an object

In the front end i send the request :

```
 CreateAccount(){
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('cv',this.cv);
        axios({
            method : 'post',
            url : 'http://localhost:1323/restricted/Profile',
            headers: {
              'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + this.$store.state.token,
              'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data;`,
            },
            data : formData})
```

In the backend with golang, i use []byte to store this data like this :

```
Cv             []byte    `json:"cv" form:"cv" query:"cv"`
```

But this field return as an empty array, maybe there is a missmatch data type in here so they just don't store my data ?? please help. I have struggle with this 1 task(sending a file in the front end and receive that file in the backend, store it in the postgre db) for more than 3 days
Ther are actually no error. It just that mine Cv varible in the backend return empty, there are nothing in it whereas the other field had the correct value

Comment: Maybe try using a string instead of a byte slice and see if you get anything. Internally a string is an array of bytes and you can just cast to a byte slice if you need to `[]byte(s)` though this will copy the bytes in memory since a string is immuteable.

Comment: @AndrewW.Phillips I have update the question, i'll try your method to see if i could get anything

Comment: Include the code that handles the request in the question.